# Access two different security enabled web services from single metro client

Tags: jax-ws, apache-axis, java-metro-framework, wsit

A similar question was posted as [question:is-there-a-way-to-use-multiple-wsit-client-xml..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790958/is-there-a-way-to-use-multiple-wsit-client-xml-files-in-the-same-netbeans-project/4094462#4094462). I have two different **WS-Security** enabled web services using **Metro client** and I want to access them using a single client. I believe this will require two **wsit-client.xml** to be defined in the client project. Is it possible to define two wsit-client.xml files? or am I missing something. I believe using Axis2 +rampart this is possible by using two different policy files. I am trying to avoid using Axis2+rampart as this will require some 70 more jars to be added and a couple of modules in classpath which already has 50 jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://markmail.org/message/2vkc7yjffbyetaht - this might help